# Where to put UITableViewCell logic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

For a while now I've had this dilemma on my mind. A cell in UITableView is essentially a view, thus the class for UITableViewCell should take care of view related things (i.e. presentation methods, layout and so on.) and have no business logic inside of it (usually taken care of the controller). But since we don't have a controller for each cell and only a controller for the whole table, I have trouble figuring out where to put my cell-wise logic. Putting it in the cell itself breaks MVC, but putting it in the table controller makes it hard to determine what cell the method is being called from (I prefer writing subclasses for my senders if the view is action based so I can add properties to help me determine what view this is).

For instance I have a cell, that cell has a UIButton inside of it, when the button is pushed a UIPopover appears. Now where do I put the popover presentation code (The presentation appears from one specific cell, therefore I must know which cell it's being called from.)

I'd like to know what other people do in this case and what are their best practices.

Comment: You could subclass UITableView and UITableViewCell then, add a delegate method for the button. e.g. tableView:buttonWasPressedForCell: & buttonWasPressedForCell:. The tableView would conform to the cell's delegate and receive the message buttonWasPressedForCell:. Then, the tableView would send the message tableView:buttonWasPressedForCell: to it's delegate, in this case, your controller. This way, you know which UITableView and which UITableViewCell the message was sent from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you put the presentation of the popover inside the cell, then it's the best option. Why ?, because this is not logic, this is view related things and because the button who makes this action is inside your cell, then the code should be inside your cell (or you can send message(delegate) to your viewController to show that).
2. Then what is the logic ? The logic is for example: calculating, date operations, sending things to server. All these should be inside another object that we can call it `module` or `manager`.
3. The controller can exchange messages between all these objects (`view` - `model`), but the view and the module should be separated from each other.

Update:
You may want to take a look at [Single Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle

Comment: "Logic" is passing data for the popover to display, and action callbacks for cell subviews. A callback for the popover dismissal must exist also (We did something in the popover and want to save it). So presenting the popover from the cell and then calling back the tableview controller with the method for saving the data you've changed in the popover seems wrong to me. I might be biased though.

Comment: Well, the best approach is to create a protocol, and make the tableViewController the delegate, after the button is pressed, pass message to the delegate, for example cellButtonWasPressed, and the viewController should decide what to do

Comment: Same as @Jonathan's comment. I'm starting to think that this is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it's to your View Controller to handle the "filling" logic for your cells. Cells are recipient that you fill each time.

It is even said in `prepareForReuse:` of `UITableViewCell` :

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell.

So indeed, your cells shouldn't hold any logic other than displaying.

If you need logic like button in your cell, you should set a delegate (you create one protocol) to your subclass of `UITableViewCell` and then hold in your UIViewController the cell logic.

If you cell is unique, I recommend you to define your cell as a static cell (no reuse identifier). And make a strong link to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`. Then, add delegate methods for the button. e.g. `tableView:buttonWasPressedForCell:` & `buttonWasPressedForCell:`. The tableView would conform to the cell's delegate and receive the message `buttonWasPressedForCell:`. Then, the tableView would send the message `tableView:buttonWasPressedForCell:` to it's delegate, in this case, your controller. This way you know which `UITableView` and which `UITableViewCell` the message was sent from.

**Example:**

**ABCTableView.h**

```
@protocol ABCTableViewDelegate <NSObject, UITableViewDelegate>

// You may not need this delegate method in a different UIViewController.
// So, lets set it to optional.
@optional

// Instead of passing the cell you could pass the index path.
- (void)tableView:(ABCTableView *)tableView buttonWasPressedForCell:(ABCTableViewCell *)cell;

@end


@interface ABCTableView : UITableView

// Declare the delegate as an IBOutlet to enable use with IB.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<ABCTableViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**ABCTableView.m**

```
@implementation ABCTableView

@dynamic delegate;


- (void)buttonWasPressedForCell:(ABCTableViewCell *)cell
{
    // Check if the delegate responds to the selector since
    // the method is optional.
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:buttonWasPressedForCell:)])
    {
        [self.delegate tableView:self buttonWasPressedForCell:cell];
    }
}

@end
```

**ABCTableViewCell.h**

```
@protocol ABCTableViewCellDelegate;


@interface ABCTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

// Declare the delegate as an IBOutlet to enable use with IB.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<ABCTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol ABCTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

// You may not need this delegate method in a different custom UITableView.
// So, lets set it to optional.
@optional

- (void)buttonWasPressedForCell:(ABCTableViewCell *)cell;

@end
```

**ABCTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation ABCTableViewCell

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender
{
    // Check if the delegate responds to the selector since
    // the method is optional.
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonWasPressedForCell:)])
    {
        [self.delegate buttonWasPressedForCell:self];
    }
}

@end
```

**Note:**
When you dequeue the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or add the cell using Interface Builder be sure to set the cell's delegate to the tableView.

E.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ABCTableViewCell *cell = (ABCTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.delegate = tableView;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually for tasks like this I assign to cell my viewController as delegate (and define some protocol for it). Also, i keep weak reference to object from which I populate my cell, so on button's action I will forward to delegate (viewController) method like this:

```
- (void)actionOnCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell fromView:(UIView *)sender withItem:(id)sourceItem;
```

so in this  way, I know where from show my popover, and what information (appropriate to `sourceItem`) show in it.

**EDIT** Also, if there multiple controls on cell to avoid duplication of pretty similar methods you can just add one parameter to function mentioned above, and define enum of all possible actions

Answer (score 0):

Create an action handler and a data source for the cell. Have your data source conform to the data source protocol (View Model). Then there is no need for the cell to even know about the data model.

In the interface: TableViewCell

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SomeTableViewCellActionHandler> actionHandler;

@protocol SomeTableViewCellActionHandler <NSObject>
- (void)cell:(SomeTableViewCell *)cell didReceiveStartButtonAction:(UIButton *)button;
- (void)cell:(SomeTableViewCell *)cell didReceivePauseButtonAction:(UIButton *)button;
- (void)cell:(SomeTableViewCell *)cell didReceiveClearButtonAction:(UIButton *)button;
@end
```

Implementation

```
- (void)prepareActionsForControls
{
    [self.startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleStartButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePauseButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.clearButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleClearButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)handleStartButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.actionHandler cell:self didReceiveStartButtonAction:sender];
}

- (void)handlePauseButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.actionHandler cell:self didReceivePauseButtonAction:sender];
}

- (void)handleClearButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.actionHandler cell:self didReceiveClearButtonAction:sender];
}
```

When you create your cell in the View Controller
create an action handler that conforms to the MyTableViewCellActionHandler protocol, pass the action handler the View Controller if it needs to do presentation.

```
cell.actionHandler = self.tableViewCellActionHandler;
```

You may also provide a datasource for your cell and pass in a View Model. (MVVM) This will allow you to keep only presentation code in the cell and keep all of  your business logic where it belongs. Separation of concerns.